# Is it ok to watch a media that promote homosexuality?

Tags: theravada, ethics, mahayana, buddha

this is my first post

I have researched what the buddhist sutra says about Homosexuality...I found Saddhama Smrty Uposttana sutra and Upasakasila sutra that said homosexuality is sexual misconduct and in the first sutra it even mention hell

https://youtu.be/g7aikfMui2M

So my question..I am not a homosexual but I am a hardcore fan of Kpop(korean music pop) since 7 years, and there is a lots of promotion and depiction of Homosexuality in concert, reality programs that are about the boy bands groups, that even fans create something called fan fiction and a lots of time it talks about sex and even rape among the boy bands..I dont read fanfiction because it's bad.. but I watch a boyband and they also do some homosexual acts..I have been turning blind eye but I was concerned what buddhism think about that..even there is a lots of fans who watch bl series(boy love aka homosexual story) such fans called Fujoshi( which is japanese words means spoiled girls, which they like to watch boy acts on boys) and I am also realized that I am also a fujoshi and I cant help was drown to watch such series( I didnt but felt like craving to watch it) and it's very popular in Buddhist countries..so I thought more buddhists should discuss this thing and its influence among the teenagers because the vast majority of fans are but I am adult..any way

Should buddhist refrain from watching such media?

I also wanted to know what Buddha think of celebrities and i know that in Talaputta sutta buddha said actors would go to hell( I am not sure if that also include singers) I am usually watch music videos and some shows by boy band i dont watch movies or series..but it appear like the buddha also think the one who watch entertainment is not good

Any way...sorry for being long..i just need guidance regarding that..i am also follower of mahayana pureland buddhism but even pali sutta, i will still look to it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism deals with suffering and how to become permanently free from it.

Superficial and conceptual things like sexuality are useless in that regard, hence the focus merely on ultimate reality.

Comment: That doesn't sound compatible with non-dualism.

Comment: If it's useless...then the Buddha wouldn't need to talk about it in the sutra..the argument doesnt make sense

Comment: @LoveJeju. These suttas are later add-ons by Mahayana Buddhists and has nothing to do with the original Pali Canon from the time of the Buddha.

Comment: but I am follower of Mahayana Buddhism..I don't understand the sectarian bashing..I am not a theravadin..I don't believe only in the Pali canon...the answers are just very unhelpful

Comment: Sorry about that. I hope you will get an answer that you can use. In Theravada Buddhism sexual orientation doesn't matter. What matters is the 5 Aggregates of Clinging and how to become free from that burden. If you see a man or a woman it's still just "seeing", i.e. the Eye-faculty is working. If you hear the voice of a man or woman it's still just "hearing". If you like a man or a woman it's still just a "feeling" etc. That's what I meant with ultimate reality instead of dealing with concepts like man, woman, etc. Maybe you can ask a Mahayana monk about this online or in a temple/center?

Answer (score 0):

'Going to hell' in Buddhism is not like in Christianity, it is not a judgement. Ksitigharba went to hell, and is a bodhisattva.

You should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_and_sexual_orientation

Stigma, and denying or silencing issues around sexuality, cause huge amounts of suffering, prevent reporting and accountability, and make many people's traumas more difficult to recover from.

Buddhist monastic sanghas, as described in the Wikipedia article, had specific issues in terms of maintaining the reputation of the sangha, given monks relied on alms from the community to be able to practice. It is clear though that sexual misconduct in Buddhism is *about harms*, and in modern times we understand homosexual relationships can be conducted without harms, and that many of the historical associations with harms were actually a result of social stigma, and of having been pushed to the edges of society and lacking social support and protections. Gay marriage must be seen as a positive, making lasting commitments to mutual support and family life. Issues around rape and sexual exploitation among boy bands, are absolutely sexual misconduct, in Buddhism and wider society, but must be separated from homosexuality more generally. The studio system in Korea, is far more the problem in that regard, than sexuality.

I found this article on the emergence of Yaoi manga very interesting: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-35714067
Yaoi as an overwhelmingly female-led genre, in terms of both writers and readers, is a fascinating example of women getting to explore their own sexuality in their own way, where sexual awkwardness, discomfort with sex acts, and with sexual persona and societies views, can be explored through the alternate gender. The origin of the word yaoi comes from a (self-deprecating & somewhat ironic) portmanteau of "no climax, no point, no meaning", which highlights how it is (primarily) about romance and flirting, rather than being porn.

Such gender and sexuality exploration, where hard boundaries are not so enforced (ie, 'you are this or that category even by one experience' or even just curiosity, making it more difficult for people to explore and understand themselves), is as I understand it part of the global rise of Kpop, and especially part of it's appeal among teenage girls. Eg BTS the first Kpop band to be nominated for the Grammies https://www.dazeddigital.com/music/article/42565/1/bts-gender-fluidity-teen-angst-column

Androgeny and gender-nonconformity has commonly been a feature of music and musicians where the fan base is primarily female, which can be linked to the easing of pressure on girls to conform to gender roles and express gendered behaviours. This has generally helped support social progress and freedom of expression for all. Sexuality is a powerful factor, in the lives of individuals and in society and culture; I suggest that a measure of playfulness and humour about it, can help release the grip it can take on our minds.

Celebrities are like the devas: not in the best realm for awakening, which is to be an ordinary human. Because devas are likely to be distracted or self-satisfied in ways that don't help with spiritual practice. Monks are not allowed music, or to watch theatre, but they dedicate themselves full time to Buddhist practice, and that is not the only way to benefit from Buddhism. As a lay person, some ways of following celebrities can be unhealthy, taking on bad influences or attitudes, using them as a distraction, or feeling bad by comparing yourself. But there *can* absolutely be positive influences, though they are probably much less common. Taylor Swift is I think a great example of someone using their influence positively.

I have to say, the Kpop industry sounds INTENSELY exploitative of young people, I don't know how that can be changed by fans, but I hope it will be. Singers getting to speak out, and supporting independent singers who've left the big labels, may be part of it.

Comment: That's basically are contradictory to say homosexuality is allowed in buddhism based on buddhist sutra..I actually dont understand why many seems to just ignore the sutra...but it's ok..I was look answer from a knowledgable person from buddhist sutra perspective..I am not an ex christian and not western..so I dont understand why christianity have to be mentioned.. and ksitigarbha going to hell to save living being..not going there means it's to reborn in hell is ok..he is an enlightened being not like us... being reborn in hell might not even found our way again..master hsuan Hua said thar

Comment: @LoveJeju: It is difficult to understand you. Where is Christianity mentioned? The bare bones of the sutras on these issues is there in the Wikipedia article. "According to some scholars, early Buddhism appears to have placed no special stigma on homosexual relations, since the subject was not mentioned." Then an explanation about certain sexualities/gender identities not being allowed in the sangha, with discussion of how the words for those are unclear. What sutra or other statement have you read that you claim makes homosexuality 'wrong'?

Comment: Ok..but you didnt basically checked the youtube link above..it have two sutra saddhama smrty uposthana sutra and upasakasila sutra..where homosexuality are clearly mentioned as sexual misconduct and the first one even mention hell...I did not want to debate whether homosexuality is ok or not..I just needed a guidance regarding consumption of such media but I guess may be I did ask on the wrong place..any way master hsuan Hua talked about that. So may be it was better to ask his follower

Comment: You should know both of those are later Mahayana sutras, that are not found in the Pali Canon, and do not date from the time of the Buddha. There are substantial criticisms to the badly made Youtube video you linked, in the comments.

Comment: I did mention clearly in my post that I am follower of Mahayana buddhism..you seems never reading the post..I dont believe its later add that's theravada perspective..and the comments in the video doesnt matter...the sutra does..not people desires...so any way..I think I am asking in the wrong place

Comment: It's the perspective of scholars who look for textural clues, earliest extant copies, and commentaries. I practice a Mahayana style. But I accept the Heart Sutra, Lotus Sutra, and other important texts in Mahayana thought are later additions to the Tripitaka, which I regard as core to understanding Buddha's teaching.